# is there maximum figsize in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I am trying to save a large picture (which is actually larger than resolution of my display), however I get the same size png pictures when increasing figsize. So for two example below I get exactly the same files:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 100))
ax[0].plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
ax[1].plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
fig.savefig('test1.png')
plt.close()
```

and second:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 150))
ax[0].plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
ax[1].plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
fig.savefig('test2.png')
plt.close()
```

Is there a way to create a larger picture please?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get 146KB and 192KB for the size of the images

Comment: Are you using xming from a linux server?

Comment: thanks @DavidG. What if you use larger figsize like (10, 1000) and (10, 2000) let's say?

Comment: @akozi, windows

Comment: Where and how are you running this? Did you open the produced images in a image viewer and checked how large (in pixels) they are? There might be a maximum optainable figure size but at 150 inch you should not have reached that point yet. The code above produces two different images for me as expected.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am running it in windows via pycharms, if I open pictures in paint for instance - they are exactly the same size. my issue is that I have nrows=20 and I was the picture to be super long that I can put it into an email. otherwise all plots are very narrow

Comment: Can you try outside of pycharm? There might be some issue of pycharm using interactive mode or so.

Comment: I'm having this same problem and I'm not using PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, indeed the issue was with PyCharm. 
(I am using 2017.2.3)

Therefore if anyone's having the same issue - just try outside of PyCharm!

Answer (score 0):

I work in a Jupyter `notebook`. What works for me was playing with the `dpi` argument.

So:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(25,15)) # small, even for figsize=(150,75)

plt.figure(figsize=(25,15), dpi= 150) # larger

plt.figure(figsize=(25,15), dpi= 300) # largest
```